# Syntax Match PLSQL Label

Tags: syntax-highlighting, gvim

A PLSQL Label uses this syntax `<<LABEL_NAME>>`
How can I highlight everything inside and including the opening and closing angle braces?

I've tried the following:

```
syn match  PLS_label "/[<<].*[>>]/"
syn match  PLS_label "/[<][<].*[>][>]/"
syn match  PLS_label /[<<].*[>>]/
syn match  PLS_label /[<][<].*[>][>]/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a character class around `<`, and you should probably not use a greedy `.*` match (would break on `<<Label1>> <<Label1>>`).

This worked for me:

```
syntax match PLS_label "<<[^>]\+>>"
```

(though you only get colors if you use a highlight command on `PLS_label`).

OP points out a region using `<<` and `>>` as start and end is also possible.

Comment: see also `:help syn-region`.  Thus,   `syntax region PLS_label start="<<" end =">>"`